# Cannot connect to local SQL server using C# Net Core 5.0 , works remotely

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

I was making changes to some old code base, and decided to move a .net 4.5 C# project to core 5.0.

I tested everything on my local machine and it worked, however the executable is to be run on the same server that hosts the SQL Server. The server is an Azure VM.

When I published the .exe, and copied it to the server and ran it there, through a local account in remote desktop - I got an error when connection to the SQL server!

The error is:

```
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (53): The network path was not found.
```

To debug I made a tiny console app. Build it on my laptop and tested it.
When running it on the Server I get the error above

This is the code

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
namespace connectiontest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cs="Data Source=<SERVER>.<REGION>.cloudapp.azure.com;User ID=<sqlusername>;Password=<password>;Initial Catalog=<dbname>;";
            var con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            con.Close();
            
        }
    }
}
```

If I make the same console program in old .net  4.72, using system.data.sqlclient it works.

I tried using system.data.sqlclient instead of Microsoft.Data.sqlclient, but get the same result.

I tried adding tcp: and port number to data source to force a TCP/IP connection, but that only changes the error from named pipes provider to TCP.

Named pipes and TCP/IP is enabled for the server, which makes sense since we have no trouble connection from remote, or even locally, just not when using core?

I feel like I am missing something obvious here, but I cannot see it

Comment: You're not using ODBC drivers, so why not `"Server=<SERVER>.<REGION>.cloudapp.azure.com;..."`, or since it's on the same machine `"Server=localhost;..."`?

Comment: Good question - I just copied it from the old value. 
I just tested and with Server= instead of "Data Source=" i still get the same error.